# Port Forwarding for FTP server

Tags: networking, ftp, port-forwarding

I'll get straight to the point. I recently set up a FileZilla server to get all my files anywhere to watch or access. I have already set up the user and directory I want to access, as well as picking the port. The problem is my NAT router. I have put exceptions in my firewall on both machines for the port I used (7780) and I have set my passive mode to get my external IP from the filezilla site, which I heard is supposed to help me, but I can't connect to the machine using my external or internal IP's (both connected to LAN). I have tried to forward the port to that IP, but I think in doing so I lose the ability to connect within the network because all traffic even going from the machine forwards back to it.
Here's What I need to know:

- How does the passive mode work?
- How do I configure the ports to forward to that machine while still being able to connect to my server within my household)?

LOGS:

[image: Settings]

[image: Settings V2]

[[image: Attempt to connect[3]]

What I see on client computer:

[image]

Comment: Show us some logs first.

Comment: I added logs to the post

Comment: Thank you, I will delete in a bit when I confirm this solution works

Comment: While now I am able to connect to the server within my house by using my internal IP for the server, I am unable to connect from my phone from using my external IP. I have my setting to get my external IP from the filezilla site, but it isn't responding and the server doesn't acknowledge its getting any connections.

Comment: What's your IP bindings settings in FileZilla server?

Comment: It's ok I got it. I'm on a NAT network so I just rerouted external connections only from ports 5000-5010 to the server, and now I am able to use the internal IP while in my house, and the external one on cellular data and still connect. Mission accomplished!

Answer (score 1):

For FTP you need to forward both "FTP" and "data" ports. You forwarded only the control port, passive mode needs another port(s).

I would recommend to forward port 7780 -> 21 and port range 7781-7789 -> 7781-7789.

In the first dialog set listen port 21, in the second tick "custom port settings" and type 7781-7789.

Comment: Do not answer duplicate questions. A mere comment pointing the OP to the existing question is preferred.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to allow not only the FTP port, but also the data port through my firewall on both machines, as well as forwarding the ports used for passive mode to that machine.